# Как описать интерфейс объекта, но создавать его без значений

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Я новичок в typescript, у меня возник вопрос по поводу начального состояние объектов для которых описан interface или тип

Допустим у нас есть объект для которого мы описали интерфейс:

```
interface IObj {
   foo: string,
   bar: boolean
}

const obj: IObj  = {}
```

Очевидно что тайпскрипт выдаст ошибку, потомучто в obj нету foo и bar.

Есть ли какието подходы в TS что бы избежать изначального описания, кроме оператора ?

Возник такой вопрос, потомучто я использую React + Redux и мне с api приходят большие объемы данных с соответствующей структурой, я хочу избежать начального состояния в state.

Comment: можно использовать тип [Partian<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Comment: С другой, стороны, если поля обязательные, странно пытаться инициализировать объект без них.

Comment: @Grundy, Спасибо за ответ, это единственное решение в такой ситуации? Мне действительно придется описывать всю структуру например из 40 вложенных полей?

Comment: _я хочу избежать начального состояния в state_ указывай начальное значение `null` для всего `state`, а не отдельных полей

Comment: @Grundy выдает ошибку :(     Тип "null" не может быть назначен для типа "IObject | undefined"

Comment: замени на `undefined` :)

Comment: @Grundy получается лучше все таки описывать начальное состояние state, просто с пустыми данными? всмысле пустые строки объекты и тд?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134280/discussion-between-grundy-and-user469485).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае с моим окружением в initialState я просто ставлю

```
const initialState = undefined;
```

И это решает мою проблему